# Magic line Navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav

I am using the magic line navigation for a website but would not like to have a home menu button, as the logo will do this. What is the best method for integrating a logo into this menu without changing the current layout? p.s. the logo should be appearing next to the menu on the left, did not want to add all the css in.

Attaching the js fiddle link.
http://jsfiddle.net/LjxmG/

// DOM Ready

```
$(function() {

var $el, leftPos, newWidth;
    $mainNav2 = $("#example-two");

/*
    EXAMPLE ONE
*/

/* Add Magic Line markup via JavaScript, because it ain't gonna work without */
$("#example-one").append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");

/* Cache it */
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

$magicLine
    .width($(".current_page_item").width())
    .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

$("#example-one li").find("a").hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    leftPos = $el.position().left;
    newWidth = $el.parent().width();

    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: leftPos,
        width: newWidth
    });
}, function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
        width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
    });    
});

/*
    EXAMPLE TWO
*/

$mainNav2.append("<li id='magic-line-two'></li>");

var $magicLineTwo = $("#magic-line-two");

$magicLineTwo
    .width($(".current_page_item_two").width())
    .height($mainNav2.height())
    .css("left", $(".current_page_item_two a").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $(".current_page_item_two a").position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLineTwo.width())
    .data("origColor", $(".current_page_item_two a").attr("rel"));

$("#example-two a").hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    leftPos = $el.position().left;
    newWidth = $el.parent().width();
    $magicLineTwo.stop().animate({
        left: leftPos,
        width: newWidth,
        backgroundColor: $el.attr("rel")
    })
}, function() {
    $magicLineTwo.stop().animate({
        left: $magicLineTwo.data("origLeft"),
        width: $magicLineTwo.data("origWidth"),
        backgroundColor: $magicLineTwo.data("origColor")
    });    
});

/* Kick IE into gear */
$(".current_page_item_two a").mouseenter();

});
```

Comment: Doing it with css is totally possible but does this menu has to be responsive?
Are you sure you can't modify the layout to add your logo like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LjxmG/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your css

```
#logo{
      display: inline-block;}
.nav-wrap{
          display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: Ahh I seem to have forgotten to mention that I would like the logo to have the magic line also, just to see how it looks.

Comment: just put your logo in li for example <ul class="group" id="example-one">
            <li><img src="images/logo.png" /> </li>
        
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="About-Us.html" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
          </ul>

Comment: and delete logo before <ul> tag and put that logo image in li

Comment: Hi again, I am faced with a new problem. Have added the logo as a list item but want the text menu items to align right and the logo left. How can I do this within the list, thanks?

Comment: add float:left to logo and float:right to rest of the list items

Answer (score 1):

I added float:left; to the logo and the menu, I didn't change the html, only changed the css http://jsfiddle.net/LjxmG/4/

```
#logo {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}

.nav-wrap {
    float: left;
}
```

I also changed the padding on #example-one, this was breaking the menu.